# For Loop Prompt Repeating 5 Times

Tags: for-loop, cout, cin

I am trying to write a simple command line student database program and when the prompt begins the loop in the for loop it repeats 5 times when asking for the next student's name.  What is wrong here?  This is what I have.

Output:

Enter number of students in class: 5
Enter student name: John Smith
Enter student name: Enter student name: Enter student name: Enter student name:

---

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
    std::cout << "Enter student name: ";
    std::cin.get(studentName[i]);
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what you expect, since you said there are 5 students in the class?

Comment: what exactly you want????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `std::cout << "Enter student name: ";` is inside the `for` loop so it displays 5 times. This is what you want to do. Just enter the name 5 times.

Comment: I'm trying to add 5 different students to the array and then I'm coding to add more code so I can add scores to them and calculate their average.  I want the prompt to appear after I enter each student name until 5 students are in the array, then move on to the next block of code which I have yet to add.

Comment: If you want the prompt to appear after the for loop, you need to give another `std::cin` outside the for loop. And then you can do whatever you want to do with that input.